# Scala: List of class objects printing the class variable/attributes

Tags: scala, list, class, oop, instance

I'm trying to print the variables of class instances stored within a list. An getter method should be automatic generated for me to use but I cannot use it.

```
case class InventoryItem(var inventory_item_name: String, var 

number_of_available_items: Int)

    class InventoryManagement() {


    private var inventory_storage = new ListBuffer[InventoryItem]()


    //New function that connects list to the front.
    def attachToList(): Unit = {}

    //////////////////////////////
    //ADDING AN ITEM TO THE LIST//
    //////////////////////////////
    def addItems(): Unit = {
      var inventory_item_name_input = "0"
      var number_of_available_items_input = "0"
      inventory_item_name_input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("What is the name of the item you want to add?")
      number_of_available_items_input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("How many are there?")
      inventory_storage += new InventoryItem(inventory_item_name_input,number_of_available_items_input.toInt)
    }
    ///////////////////
    //PRINT THE LIST //
    ///////////////////
    def listItems(): Unit = {
      println(); println();
      println(inventory_storage)
      println(inventory_storage.InventoryItem.inventory_item_name) // Failure
      println(inventory_storage.inventory_item_name) // Failure
      inventory_storage.foreach(println(inventory_item_name)) // More Failure
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your code looks like this to add elements to the ListBuffer.

```
case class InventoryItem(var inventory_item_name: String, var number_of_available_items: Int)

var inventory_storage = new ListBuffer[InventoryItem]()

inventory_storage += InventoryItem("a1",1)
inventory_storage += InventoryItem("a2",2)
inventory_storage += InventoryItem("a3",3)
inventory_storage += InventoryItem("a4",4)
```

Now to access the variables of the case classes inside the listBuffer, you can declare write your foreach as

```
inventory_storage.foreach{
  x => println(x.inventory_item_name)
}
```

Comment: Note that the OP will not be notified if he didn't comment on your answer, the `@` does nothing for users that did not participate in a conversation.

Comment: @Chaitanya Waikar Thank you for your assistant. The "=>" function arrow has more usage than I anticipated.